# User access in Azure AD with Graph Explorer vs Power Automate

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

We have a dynamics environment and I am using Powerautomate in order to make call to Microsoft Graph, in order to update some users in Azure.

I use the Invoke an HTTP request to perform my actions in PowerAutomate.

Before using PowerAutomate, I always test my actions using the Graph Explorer(https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)  to make sure the syntax is correct and that I have the right access to perform it. However, I have been having problems with some actions , which makes me question my understanding of the rights in Azure.

For example, I tried doing this one :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations (post)

{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "4d86be94-b2d3-ed11-a7c7-0022483d0128",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "http://365e.pro",
  "invitedUserDisplayName": "David Brunelle",
  "sendInvitationMessage": false,
  "invitedUserMessageInfo": {
    "customizedMessageBody": "Message"
  }
}
```

When I do that in the Graph Explorer, I can clearly see it worked when I go check the user in Azure. However, when I try in in PowerAutomate, I get this

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to perform requested operation by the application '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. ControllerName=MSGraphInviteAPI, ActionName=CreateInvite, URL absolute path=/api/7a272831-1132-49e5-aa92-2c4f6ad1ff1d/invites",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "cfe808e8-8185-4414-bed6-7b1b6a785a00",
      "date": "2023-04-06T20:07:38",
      "client-request-id": "cfe808e8-8185-4414-bed6-7b1b6a785a00"
    }
  }
}
```

If I try a simple get action, I see no problem.
Usually, when I have an access problem, I can see it in the graph explorer and then I can add or remove access, test it again and when I get it right, it works in PowerAutomate too.

What am I missing here ??? Why would the Graph Explorer works but not PowerAutomate with the same user.

Here is what I use in Power Automate

[image]

In this picture, I enter the same credentials as the graph explorer.
[image]

When I try this action, which use the same credential, it works fine.
[image]

Comment: With all due respect, your question assumes that we accept that your method of authentication is using the same approach and user that’s being used in the graph explorer call. Can you show us portions of your flow that is doing the work to authenticate?

Comment: Indeed, I do not know how Graph Explorer works and if I did, I would probably have figured it out on my own. I will edit with more details.